# Python requests.get returns 500 for only one specific url in Google Cloud Function, works fine in local machine

Tags: python-requests, google-cloud-functions, http-status-code-500

I have a google cloud function to get response of the two urls, but I got 500 for the second, the first isfine:
https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/5158389/
https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/5158194/

```
url = 'https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/5158194/'
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

And both works fine in the local machine. Any ideas? Thanks

Updates:

So far, I have tried set TLS and cache-control in the header, none works:

```
class Tls12HttpAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections, maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

s = requests.Session()
s.mount(url, Tls12HttpAdapter())
r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
```

I also tried using curl to get the output:

`result = subprocess.run("curl -i --tlsv1.2 https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/5158389/", shell=True, capture_output=True)`

I found the difference between the working url and non-working url is in the cache-control field:
the working one:

```
CompletedProcess(args='curl -i --tlsv1.2 https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/5158389/', 
returncode=0, stdout=b'HTTP/2 200 \r\naccess-control-allow-headers: content-Type, accept, origin, X-Requested-With,
 DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion\r\naccess-control-allow-methods: PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, MERGE, OPTIONS\r\naccess-control-allow-origin: *\r\n
cache-control: public, max-age=180\r\ncontent-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8\r\n
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319\r\nx-powered-by: ASP.NET\r\ndate: Sun, 08 Dec 2019 23:26:38 GMT\r\nx-device: default\r\n\r\n{\r\n "meet": {
```

the non-working one:

```
CompletedProcess(args='curl -i --tlsv1.2 https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/5158194/', returncode=0, stdout=b'HTTP/2 500 \r\naccess-control-allow-headers: content-Type, accept, origin, X-Requested-With, 
DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion\r\naccess-control-allow-methods: PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, MERGE, OPTIONS\r\naccess-control-allow-origin: *\r\n
cache-control: no-cache\r\ncontent-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8\r\nexpires: -1\r\npragma: no-cache\r\nx-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319\r\nx-powered-by: ASP.NET\r\n
content-length: 36\r\ndate: Sun, 08 Dec 2019 23:22:35 GMT\r\nx-device: default\r\n\r\n{"Message":"An error has occurred."}'
```

The requests.get() for the two urls both works in the local machine, but the second won't work in google cloud function, means the google server sends the http request differently? or the racing server treats the two url differently?

Comment: I think I'm hearing you say that you have a GCP Cloud Function that, when called, itself makes an HTTPS get request against the URL you have listed above but you are saying that this request fails with a 500 response code.  I would try and capture the full request sent by the Cloud Function and the full response received.  Look in the response for further clarifying information on why the server returned 500.

Comment: Yes, in the google cloud function I made a request to get the response of that url. The response the google cloud function got is 500, the content is {'message': 'an error occurred'}, nothing else. One thing I don't get is the same code works fine in my local machine, same headers, but fails in the cloud function, and other urls work also fine in the cloud function, just this one doesn't. Driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the issue, I found what is the problem, but I wasn't able to solve it (because of my low python skill).

I got an error 500 by doing this with curl:

```
curl -i --tlsv1.0 https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/5158194/
```

It works with `--tlsv1.1` and `--tlsv1.2`. The version of TLS used should be the issue.

I tried to force an higher version of requests in the `requirements.txt` file without change. I added the parameter `verify=False` to the get request without better results.

I'm only at the half way. I hope this help you for going further in your debug.

**EDIT**

This morning (12-09-2019), I retried on Cloud Shell, and all tls versions are working:

```
guillaume_blaquiere@cloudshell:~ curl -i --tlsv1.0 https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/5158194/ | head                                                                                                                                   
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-Type, accept, origin, X-Requested-With, DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, MERGE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: public, max-age=180
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

guillaume_blaquiere@cloudshell:~ curl -i --tlsv1.1 https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/5158194/ | head                                                                                                                                   
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-Type, accept, origin, X-Requested-With, DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, MERGE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: public, max-age=180
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

guillaume_blaquiere@cloudshell:~ curl -i --tlsv1.2 https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/5158194/ | head
HTTP/2 200
access-control-allow-headers: content-Type, accept, origin, X-Requested-With, DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion
access-control-allow-methods: PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, MERGE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: public, max-age=180
content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-powered-by: ASP.NET

guillaume_blaquiere@cloudshell:~ curl -i --tlsv1 https://api.racing.com/v1/en-au/meet/details/5158194/ | head
HTTP/2 200
access-control-allow-headers: content-Type, accept, origin, X-Requested-With, DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion
access-control-allow-methods: PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, MERGE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: public, max-age=180
content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

Maybe an update on the API side? My function still returns 500. Not understandable!

Anyway, curl and subprocess in Cloud Function aren't recommended, you don't manage the underlying infrastructure (the main principle of serverless) and you don't know what to expect when you use system command.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clue, very helpful, I'll continue debugging and let you know what I find later.

Comment: I tried changing the tls and using the curl, none works, you can see the update above. You said "it works with --tlsv1.1 and 1.2", you mean in the google cloud function? or local machine? So far I can't get the results in google cloud function in anyway.

Comment: @IanJay I edited my answer. I don't understand what happens...

Comment: I tried curl on Cloud shell, none works. However, I found if I change the region of the cloud function to US and Euro, I could get the result correctly, only Asia didn't work. Don't know how your curl on Cloud shell works.

Answer (score 1):

Final Update:

I changed the region of my cloud function, and it worked.

Still don't understand why, my guess is the IP address in Asian region is blocked from the server, anyhow we live in a biased world.

Comment: Running curl from a GCE instance located in any of the Asia regions yields the same result, so I think this confirms your hypothesis.